# Promise.all() problem using setTimeout(), state not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

I have an arrow function that is invoked from `cDM` to retrieve the updated status of schedules every 20 seconds with a `setTimeout()`.

```
componentDidMount() {
    //get request to /schedules
    //update state with response data
    this.getUpdatedStatus();
}
```

Each schedule present at `/schedules` looks like this:

```
"data": {
"id": "2147483605",
"selfUri": "/schedules/2147483605",
"type": "Schedule",
"status": "Pending",
}
```

So in the below method, each `schedule.selfUri` is requested, and I'm attempting to update `status` of each schedule.

```
    getUpdatedStatus = () => {
//fetch updated status,
const schedules = this.state.schedules;
Promise.all(
  schedules.map(schedule =>
    axios({
      method: "get",
      url: schedule.selfUri,
    })
  )
)
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response);
    const isIncomplete = response.some(r => r.status !== "Complete");
    console.log(isIncomplete);
    if (isIncomplete) {
      this.timeout = setTimeout(() => this.getUpdatedStatus(), 20000);
    }
    this.setState(
      {
        scheduleStatus: isIncomplete ? "Pending" : "Complete",
      },
      () => {
        console.log(this.state.scheduleStatus);
        console.log(this.state.schedules);
      }
    );
  })
  .catch(error => console.log(error.response));
```

};

The `setTimeout` function is working and requesting every 20 seconds to retrieve a possible update on the status. The object response eventually returns a status of `complete` but the value is not re-rendering in my table. I believe there is a problem with my promise chain and using `setTimeout` isn't updating my `this.state.scheduleStatus` when it completes. I have attached a codesandbox that gives a better view of my issue.

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ympo7pr0xx)

Comment: can you provide working fiddle which show the problem? https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: The first thing you should do is wrap your `<fieldset>` in a `<form>` element. This will allow React to control the form elements properly. Next, it appears the component is not mounting properly.

Comment: Next, you didn't declare `scheduleStatus` as a state property, but tried to use it. So declare `scheduleStatus` as a state property. Finally, The data coming back from from the Axios call is an HTML page...not data.

Comment: I provided a codesandbox, the best I can do is mock the data inside the component. @KamilKiełczewski

Comment: @RandyCasburn The `<fieldset>` element has nothing to do with question I posted, it doesn't apply to my table. And as far as the data coming back from Axios is an HTML page, what? I had to mock the data inside the component itself, this is just a representation of what the shape of my data looks like.

Comment: @DJ2 You didn't mock the call to the "selfUri" URL. Your script actually performs the request to the URL relative to the current domain, which on Codesandbox returns an HTML page. Your Codesandbox fiddle doesn't help us troubleshoot the issue as is.

Comment: I think the issue might actually be with "const isIncomplete = response.some(r => r.status !== "Complete");" This seems to be looking at response.status, which is the http status. Since this is always an http status code, it will never equal 'Complete' and as such, always returns true.

Comment: @RyanGibbs You and I came to the exact same conclusion :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think your problem has anything to do with the promise chain or using `setTimeout()`. I think it's caused by incorrectly getting the value for the `isIncomplete` flag, that it always gets set to `true`.

You're setting this value by the following line:

```
const isIncomplete = response.some(r => r.status !== "Complete")
```

I think the problem here is that you're expecting the response object to be the data you've specified, which contains a `status` property with a string value, while in reality it's the response object returned by Axios, where the `status`property is the status code of the actual response (`200` when successful). Therefore, `isIncomplete` is always `true` because `r.status` never equals `"Complete"`.

Your data can be found in the `data` property and thus the aforementioned line should be like this:

```
const isIncomplete = response.some(r => r.data.status !== "Complete")
```

Comment: So the `isIncomplete` flag is working now based on `r.data.status` it changes to false when the `status = "Complete"`, but it's still not rendering `Complete` in my table.

Comment: Any ideas why the updated value for `status` isn't re-rendering?

Comment: @DJ2 There must be something else preventing the re-render then. Your code looks fine with this change and when I try it (with a mock for the request) it **does** update the text properly.

Comment: Well I figured out the issue, I was logging a state value after the `setTimeout` method that was throwing an exception before `setState` was being called.